# Getting error while running doppler run that the executable file not found in %PATH%

Tags: python, doppler

I am new to doppler. When I run the following command `doppler run -- python3` I get an error saying `Doppler Error: exec: "python3": executable file not found in %PATH%`. I am following this tutorial to save configuration data on doppler: [https://dev.to/lordghostx/build-and-deploy-a-web-app-with-python-flask-and-doppler-9jm#:~:text=The%20answer%20is%20YES%2C%20and,and%20environment%20variables%20using%20Doppler](https://dev.to/lordghostx/build-and-deploy-a-web-app-with-python-flask-and-doppler-9jm#:%7E:text=The%20answer%20is%20YES%2C%20and,and%20environment%20variables%20using%20Doppler).
I can't get through step 6. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First thing you'll want to test is if python is actually on your path. For this, go to any blank terminal and just type "python3" and "python". If you don't get an output for either, or an error saying python couldn't be found, then you have to add python to your system path. See https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows
If you don't get an output for python3, but do get one for python, try replacing `doppler run -- python3` with `doppler run -- python` and see if it works. Good luck!

Edit: "py" seems to work for you.